# Drop-shadow with polygon on safari

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, polygon, dropshadow

I tried to create some shapes in css with: `clip-path: polygon(-30% -30%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 95%);` and I also wanted to add a shadow for that container. The only solution I found was having an outer div with: `filter: drop-shadow(0.56rem 0.56rem 0 $color);`.
There is a problem with this approach on safari, as the shadow is interrupted in some places and I couldn't find the reason for that. Also because of some animations, sometimes the shadow is getting removed entirely. Did somebody found a workaround for this?

A snippet of the implementation: https://idwfx.csb.app/

[image]